# Testes unitários com Karma (typescript/angular)

Tags: typescript, testes-de-unidade, jasmine, angular

Estou tentando realizar um teste unitário para um método feitos em typescript, esse é o método:

```
createTasksForms(): void {
    this.task.forEach(task => {
        task.form = this.form.group({ name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[^ ]/)]] });
        task.form.controls.name.valueChanges.subscribe(value => { value; });
        task.canEdit = false;
    });
}
```

Consegui testá-lo até a parte do **subscribe** (cobertura de código), porém ele não adentra a parte de **(value => { value; })**, meu teste está assim por enquanto:

```
 it('should create tasks forms', async () => {
    component.task = task;
    await component.createTasksForms();
    component.task = { form: {controls: { name: { valueChanges: { } } } } };
    expect(component.task).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Vêm alguma solução?

Comment: Ta bem estranho esse seu codigo, component .task deveria ser um array pra ser percorrido pelo for each, cada elemento task tem uma propriedade form do tipo FormGroup. Esse seu codigo do subscribe agora não faz nada. Qual o ponto dele??

Comment: sua função createTasksForms não retorna nada pq vc colocou um await nela?

Comment: uma dica seria usar map invés de forEach, no javascript e programação funcional em geral mutação é algo bem ruim

Comment: Saquei, estava revendo meu código e realmente não faz sentido essa parte dele, acho que ficou algo depois que readaptamos algumas funções. Vlw :D

Answer (score -1):

Se sua task for um array do tipo task seria algo assim:

```
it('should create tasks forms', async () => {
    component.task = [...task];
    component.createTasksForms();
    expect(component.task[0].form).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.task[0].canEdit).toBeFalsy();
  });
```